# Codeigniter3 403 error on axios post with VUEJS

Tags: codeigniter, vue.js, axios, csrf

I'm getting a 403 error when I try to post a form with codeigniter, vuejs and axios. I try many ways os solve this problem around the forum and internet, but nothing work. Here is the code, thank you for your help.

P.D: Code was working with form helper (form_open ) when I have to change it to normal html form I get 403 error...I think the problem is csrf token

Codeigniter config

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_token_idic';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_idic';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
```

VUEJS and axios

```
 var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function() {
        return {
            table: [{
                n_muestra: '',
                descripcion: '',
                lote: '',
                cantidad: '',
                n_planilla: '',
                ot_interna: '',
                delete: false                
            }],
            cant_filas: 1,
            csrf_token_idic: '<?= $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>',
        }
    },
    methods:{
        validateBeforeSubmit(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
            window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = this.csrf_token_idic;

            this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {
            if (result) {

                data= { 
                    'csrf_token_idic': this.csrf_token_idic,
                    'data': this.table
                }

                axios.post(baseUrl+'create/add_internal_work_orders/'+'<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3)?>' ,data)
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
                return;
            }else{
                alert("no");
            }

        });
        }
    }
})
```

BROWSER PREVIEW

[caption](https://prnt.sc/slcgfz)

Comment: 403 can be a webserver issue, maybe not related to your code, eg permissions.  Or maybe routes - do you have a route for the POST?

Comment: @Don'tPanic yeah!...it was working normally with form_open helper...but I change it to html form and handle the request with vue...and start failing...I think the problem is crsf

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the data in the form of **FormData**.

For example:

Use in php page:

```php
<?php
 $csrf = array(
  'name' => $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(),
  'hash' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()
 );
?>
```

```
  new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data() {
                return {
                    token_name: '<?= $csrf['name']; ?>',
                    token_hash: '<?= $csrf['hash']; ?>',
...
```

```js
methods: {
validateBeforeSubmit(){
var bodyFormData = new FormData();
bodyFormData.append(this.token_name, this.token_hash);
bodyFormData.append('firstname', 'Joe');
bodyFormData.append('lastname', 'Backer');
bodyFormData.append('age', 31);
axios.post(baseUrl+'create/add_internal_work_orders/'+'<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3)?>', bodyFormData)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/security.html?highlight=security